# Find the mistake and correct it

Tags: noun-phrases

There is only one mistake in this sentence, and it is *"African"* -> *"Africa"*, but I can't understand why *"antelope similar.."* is right? Could you explain to me ?

> "A small **antelope similar** to the chamois lives in rocky places from southern **African** to the Sahara."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"A small antelope similar to the chamois" means "A small antelope *which is similar to the chamois*". The words "similar to the chamois" are an adjective-phrase describing the antelope.

Comment: +1  This is a phenomenon sometimes called [whiz-deletion](https://www.google.com/search?q=whiz-deletion); we often leave out *which is* or *which was* if it's clear from context.